# GIT начало-начал

Tags: git

2 дня читаю, не могу начать. Уже понятно, что будет потом. И все диалоги, в сети, только об этом.

1. Есть локальный сервер, на нем создан сайт.
2. Есть хостинг, на котором этот сайт будет жить, своей жизнью и будет главным.
3. Будет текущее редактирование на локальном сервере с последующим обновлением информации с хостингом. SSH доступ. Только один Пользователь-редактор.

Все!

Помогите начать... Если я все правильно понял, примерно так:

### Установка (локально)

```
$ apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext \
  libz-dev libssl-dev // необходимые библиотеки
$ apt-get install git // сама установка
```

### Первоначальная настройка (локально)

```
$ git config --global user.name "KS" // создаем имя
$ git config --global user.email info@example.com //создаем почту
```

### Создание проекта (локально)

```
$ cd proj // переходим в корень проекта
$ git init // образуется подкаталог проекта с именем .git, тут будут все файлы работающие для git
$ git add . // создаются те самые файлы
$ git commit -m 'Initial Commit' // ? Эти самые файлы закрепляются... Тут пока примерно
```

### Манипуляции (на хостинге)

...тут уже не понятно...

```
$ sh user@ip // заходим на хостинг
$ cd proj // переходим в корневую папку проекта
$ mkdir my.git // создаем такую же папку(с другим именем?) для работы git
$ cd my.git // попадаем в пустую папку
$ git init --bare    // создаем 'голый'(почему голый?) репозиторий
```

### Перенос данных (локально)

```
$ git remote add origin user@ip:proj/my.git // вроде как создается доступ
$ git push origin master // и все заливается с локального на сервер хостинга
```

...что-то создалось, но если проект мой весит около 200Мб, создалось на 15Мб, папка my.git... но где же сам проект, который должен быть в папке proj, в развернутом виде

Пожалуйста, подскажите конкретную последовательность, орфографию строк и символов.
Спасибо!

ADD. Понимаю, что тут напрашивается ответ, почитать еще несколько раз документацию. Чем я и занимаюсь, в данный момент. В программировании еще новичок. И многие термины не понятны, приходится, одновременно читать несколько документаций, сами понимаете. И это время, которого нет. Может все-таки, кто-то хоть немного объяснит на пальцах. Все ведь как обычно решается в несколько строк. Обещаю, понять логику как только попаду внутрь.

Comment: Git связан с программированием не более чем Notepad++ с оным...

Comment: вам нужно хук сделать на post-update, посмотрите в директории my.git/congig/hooks/post-update.sample этот хук должен выкатывать каким-либо образом релиз в docroot сервера (например сообщать другой программе что надо сделать pull/rsync)

Comment: @NickVolynkin при помощи Git можно совместно тексты переводить :)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что формулировка вопроса очень общая и включает множество отдельных задач, а все ответы - ссылки. Поэтому всё содержимое малополезно.

Answer (score 6):

Почитайте для начал книгу по Git, например "Pro Git" http://git-scm.com/book (есть перевод на русском)

Answer (score 4):

[Вот тут](http://githowto.com/) я узнал всё что требовалось знать про Git в начале-начал его использования. Грубо говоря "Изучи Git за X минут". Советую!

P.S: Вверху странички есть переключалка языков.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вам нужно понять, что git, как и ftp требует демона на серверной стороне. Можете использовать assembla/bitbucket/... в качестве приватного хранилища вашего кода, можете поставить на веб-сервере gitolite, как хотите.
Но то, что вы описываете идёт в разрез с тем, как git должен работать.

Comment: можно развернуть gitlab, оно достаточно просто в установке

Comment: он требует только демона ssh не надо обманывать человека. gitolite это тоже не демон.

Comment: @eicto: чем sshd не демон? и чем `git daemon` не демон, предоставляющий доступ к репозиторию? и как можно вдруг связаться с сервером по https+git, если там нет веб-демона?
мне кажется, что обвинение в обмане мной как минимум не заслужено.

я пытался объяснить принцип работы, что для того, чтобы хостить код, не достаточно просто сделать `git init` в какой-то папке на сервере, и push'ить туда не получится.

Comment: @thunder это нужно ruby ставить, а ещё python, mysql/postgres, и все их многочисленные зависимости.

Причём в описании написано "Download Ruby and compile it", за что уже можно руки оборвать.

А ещё можно попрощаться с 750МБ памяти ("768MB is the minimal memory size but we advise against this")

Comment: sshd то демон, но это ssh демон а не для git, а git daemon не нужен вообще. зачем он непонятно (ни разу не понадобилось, может от того что gitweb проще поставить на lighthttpd или ещё куда) 

обман здесь

>> Для начала вам нужно понять, что git, как и ftp требует демона на серверной стороне.

ничего он не требует, я могу origin хоть в соседней директории держать, и уж точно это не похоже на ftp.

Comment: @eicto и как вы предлагаете человеку делать push, учитывая "Есть хостинг, на котором этот сайт будет жить", через nfs?

Comment: ну про установку руби -- да, не спорю, про требования тоже, мыж не знаем что у него за сервер куда он собирается пушить :)

Comment: @pirj а nfs вы откуда взяли ? он про ssh говорил, к тому-же паблишить(выкатывать релиз) то лучше именно rsync а не push :)

Comment: смотря как делать :) можно и webhook повесить на ветку ;)

Comment: pirj, пушем из мастера это красивая утопия, на практике-же непрерывной  интеграции вы сталкиваетесь с тем что "вот этот файл переписывать нельзя", "тут надо после обновления очистить", "omg что-то пуш перестал работать"... и тд. потому что это **веб**, тут тупых исполнителей просто физически неспособных соблюдать полиси гораздо больше чем наоборот. И да всех их не разгонишь.

Comment: @eicto непрерывная интеграция - одно, а работа с ветками - другое. непрерывная интеграция как раз подразумевает частые мержи в общий develop, а gitflow - наоборот.

"вот этот файл переписывать нельзя" - решается хуком, "тут надо после обновления очистить" - тоже. пуш перестал работать - скорее всего имя локальной ветки не совпадает с именем remote'ной.

про исполнителей да, тут тяжело не согласиться. готовых рецептов на все случаи жизни нет, да и те что есть никто не читает, а вместо этого задают невразумительные вопросы здесь. мир.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тебе еще ссылка: [Git Basics](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/git-basics)